# Why does my answer have delete votes? For what reasons can an answer be deleted?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

I have [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775133/5608921). I agree with the downvote because it does not have much description. But why are there two votes for deletion on my answer? Deletion requires one of these:

> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different    question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other
> - answers barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

And I don't think any of these is applied to my answer. So why voting for deletion? Actually the answer is correct considering only question title.

P.S. I am aware of meta effect.

Comment: Since when do we consider only the question title?

Comment: The *"not even a partial answer to the actual question"* applies to your answer, I think.

Comment: Side note: the linked  question is very likely duplicate - returning JSON seem to be very common task for php. Someone with knowledge of PHP would likely be able to find such duplicate quickly and close the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The purported answer is not an answer at all—it is just a code dump! It contains absolutely no explanation of what the magic code does or how it fixes the problem. We have no idea how or why it is relevant to the question being asked.

That makes it both unverifiable and not useful. Users with delete-vote privileges are able to cast those votes however they see fit to keep the site clean (as long as they're not abusing the system).

The list you quoted is not an exhaustive list of all possible reasons why an answer might be deleted. It just enumerates the *most common* reasons. Any answer that is unclear, incomplete, redundant, or otherwise not useful is subject to deletion at the discretion of the community.

If you want to save this answer from being deleted (or argue for its undeletion, depending on how fast you are), then you should improve it to actually answer the question.