# My answer is right but I took a vote down by moderator

Tags: discussion

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039219/php-date-picker-not-show-but-show-in-another-simple-php-file)

Now.
Not to be ridiculous, also because, probably, do not know fully the rules.
Could it be two points down in my small reputation that change my day.
This I also need to understand when I have to and when I do not answer a question.

In this case, the user poses a question. The error in the code is trivial and send the working code with the attached snippet. The moderator locks the question with this motivation: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"

But why vote down my answer that, IN ANY CASE, it was correct and it took me a very small part of my time? If the answer is wrong in form, why do condemn me too?

Comment: Firstly, you can't tell who downvoted it. It could be _anyone_, mod or not. Secondly, i m guessing it's because you added no explanation. Though there are various reasons someone might downvote, e.g. code without explanation, security holes, more complex that it should be, .. and so on.

Comment: Note: anyone with reputation >= 125 can downvote, not necessarily a moderator.

Comment: Votes are anonymous; how do you know that the moderator closing the question is also voting on the post? *Note*: things happening at roughly the same time is *no evidence*. The number of times I left a comment or did something else with a post at the same time someone else voting on it are legion.

Comment: Offtopic, but relevant: [What is the meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: The problem seems to be that you answered an _off-topic_ question instead of flagging it for closure.

Comment: [Your "answer" is not an answer—it is just a code dump. It doesn't explain what is wrong with the code, or how/why your changes fixed it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342376/why-does-my-answer-have-delete-votes-for-what-reasons-can-an-answer-be-deleted/342377#342377) That means it is *not a good answer*, and explains why someone downvoted it. There are, of course, *additional* problems with the question, and it has been downvoted, too, and is on its way to being removed.

Comment: As for the answer itself, it is next to useless. It is just a code-dump, without explanation. **Why** does it fix the issue? How could I learn from that answer how to avoid the problem in my own context? Why was there a problem in the first place? The tooltip on the down-arrow tells us that it should be used when an *answer is not useful*. Your answer is not useful for future visitors.

Comment: I agree with the others, at least for now, your answer is as "good" as the question - Replace the _"Copy/Paste this:"_ with a detailed description about what the OP did wrong, and what need to be done in order to fix the problem

Comment: Ok ok ok, my mistake.  Mine is an exposure error of the matter.
Let's say that it is very strange that the user has commented positively (the code worked) and then "somebody" has adversely voted the user's question and my answer, together with the moderator's note.
Very strange, but understandable. The vote is anonymous, this is true. But the concurrency of events is truly unique. But I understand that anyone who is in the possibilities can tarnish your reputation. It's fine. Speech closed.

Comment: But reading your comments I realized one thing in particular: DO NOT TOUCH MODERATORS. I continue my contribution to answer / ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: `right != useful`. It's not clear why you think it's *"moderators"* who downvoted - anyone with [more than 125 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) can (and should!) downvote content they think is not useful. *"If the answer is wrong in form, why do condemn me too?"* - because you wrote it? But a vote doesn't condemn you, just the post.

Comment: But my reputation goes down from 197 to 195. And 197 != 195. Moreover, in parallel to this event. Anyway. Let's not make a big deal. Next time before answering I think twice. Speech closed.

Comment: @OscarZarrus You can also remove your answer if you think it's what best, it will restore the lost reputation

Comment: @OscarZarrus _"Next time before answering I think twice"_ - Don't take what is said here as an insult. We are explaining what the problems are. Initially when I joined SO, and i was wrong about something it felt bad when someone would tell me "you are wrong". But gradually I realized that this feedback is _awesome_; that person gave away some of his time for free and actually told me how to fix my problem. He was not insulting me or anything.

Comment: @OscarZarrus _"DO NOT TOUCH MODERATORS"_ Everyone having that priviledge can downvote your answer, that doesn't need a _Moderator_.

Comment: *But the concurrency of events is truly unique.* No, it really isn't. Like Martijn said, seeing a question get down voted right before/after I post a comment (or seeing a comment appear right after I vote) is extremely common. This site gets a ton of visitors; there's no good reason to think that the only people who saw your answer were the people who closed the question.

Comment: Also, regarding, `"If the answer is wrong in form, why do condemn me too?"` -- please understand that no one was "condemning you" but rather voting on the quality of your answer. Period.

Comment: not being able to see the post and going by what the comments and answer describe it i can only assume i would have downvoted the answer if your answer was *"try this"* followed by a code dump. the text that appears over the downvote button says *"This answer is not useful"* which is exactly why i downvote code dump answers which don't explain what the solution is because it certainly not useful for me to pull apart 2 localized code samples to find the fix to a problem i may be having aswell

Answer (score 19):

"Copy/Paste this" and a bunch of code is simply not a good answer. Besides, the fact that you have to manually check this code line-by-line with the question to spot the difference, it is (at least for me) completely unclear why you changed the pathes to jquery. I'm not saying this is wrong, but it needs an explanation.

You are stating that the whole problem comes from a trivial error. But there is also no explanation what this trivial error is. Even if the error is trivial for experienced people, it might not be obvious for the asker (otherwise he wouldn't have asked).

Comment: Ok,next time, I will make more careful in drafting the answer correctly. I thought of giving immediate help to the user

Comment: @OscarZarrus Actually you could do it even on this answer. Just edit, and perhaps many downvotes could be reversed (if that was the only problem with the answer).

Comment: ok enough for me to know what to answer.