# Someone voted to delete my answer - what's wrong with it?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, vote-to-delete

After reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342376/why-does-my-answer-have-delete-votes-for-what-reasons-can-an-answer-be-deleted) and a few others, I can't fathom what's prompted the deletion vote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53241047/1767412) I posted yesterday. I took time, went into detail about the two most common reasons why OpenCart fails to parse changes to code of a Twig template and both are UI related issues so I included screenshots. Is there something legitimately wrong with my answer?

For that matter, I'm a bit discouraged that I am even getting downvoted there, but I've been here long enough to know that asking "why am I getting downvoted" is a waste of time. Vote for deletion on the other hand seems rather extreme.

Comment: We don't know, mind-reading tech has not yet been invented.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - How does this answer my question "*Is there something legitimately wrong with my answer?*"

Comment: Not sure who can answer that for you, but often it's best to chalk it up to something that sometimes happens, and then move on

Comment: Yeh, I guess the situation is this: if you are *guessing* the problem, you may be right but are liable to downvoting / deletion. I *sometimes* take this risk, but only when I think it's likely to pay off. If I can, I then go back and edit the question into shape so that the Q&A becomes useful to the wider community. Sounds like some reviewers are trigger-happy on the delete button, no recourse I'm afraid. If you want, you can post a new Q&A with a better written question. I've had to resort to this too.

Comment: I am not up on the tech involved so I can’t help evaluate your answer on its merits. If I had to guess (and it is a guess): people don’t like “write my code for me” questions, and want to discourage them. The best way to discourage them is to ensure they never get answers. The bar is high on SE, and many users care deeply about keeping it that way. Again: a guess, speculation. But note the 4 upvotes on the MCVE comment beneath the question.

Comment: The delete votes are supposed to be used if the answer is extremely low quality or does not attempt to answer the question. In your case the vote is unwarranted.

Comment: @DanBron - the comment you mentioned and the upvotes it garnered all happened before the OP posted the code he tried - so at the time it all made a lot of sense.  But as it stands now, how is this a "write my code for me" question?  He presented his code and it's perfectly fine.  His problem is almost certainly related to the mechanics of how Opencart caches the code in his template.  As a full time Opencart dev and project contributor I can tell you that this is an extremely common issue and both Q&A will have broad benefit to others.

Comment: That question was featured in a meta question yesterday.  Wasn't that you?  It got the question re-opened.  Not a terribly great idea, but that's not unusual when meta focuses attention.  Called the "meta-effect".  Which does have its downsides as well, easy enough to get a cranky meta visitor to start voting as well.  Do stop fretting over a single vote, it does take 3 to get it deleted.

Comment: @billynoah I can appreciate that. I'm not involved in that Q&A or the Opencart tech, so I can't make any comments about the merits of the question (now or before) or answer.  But the quality-control people here are very fast (because we are constantly flooded with new LQQs) and relatively unforgiving. Often it's best to leave a Q to its fate (as OP) and then ask a new one, better.

Comment: @HansPassant - yep it was me.  I think that was the first time I've ever voted to re-open a question.  For the matter it's the first time I've ever had someone vote to delete my answer!  IMO, it's a very good question and an important one because it comes up constantly in my field. Maybe the existence of this Q&A might save me from answering it another 20 times this year - which is why I wanted it answered.  I'm glad it got re-opened but I understand your theory about grumpy meta users.

Comment: It is always a good idea to edit the question you are answering into shape.

Comment: Maybe your answer appeared in the LQ review queue? It's not LQ imo, but a lot of good answers appear there, and it's why we have the review process in the first place, instead of just immediately deleting auto-flagged posts. It's possible someone wasn't paying full attention when reviewing and just clicked the "Delete" option by accident.

Answer (score -1):

Didn't vote in any way on that answer, although I just voted to close the question.

The question does not present any issue in a reproducible way, and I believe the answer is mostly a guess about one or another caching issue.

The issue the questioner faces could simply be caused by them not editing the right file, caching at a different level, or a piece of code not in evidence. **The code they do include simply doesn't show evidence of any problems.**

As such, not that I would vote to delete your answer, but answering your point about *"what's wrong with the it"*:

**It's mostly an incomplete guess under a question that should be closed; and not particularly useful because by existing under that question is hardly discoverable.**

Answer (score -2):

Five people elected to close the question because they thought it was "too broad".  After that was done, someone felt like the question was so unsalvageable that it merited deletion.

Myself, not knowing anything about Opencart, can't objectively judge if it's poor or good.  I certainly wouldn't vote to *delete* it as I don't see anything in there that's so bad it can't survive on the site.

No real way to determine why someone cast a delete vote on the question, honestly.  But typically it does follow the pattern of someone believing that the question should not be on the site anymore.

Thankfully five other people disagreed with this assertion and the question's reopened.

Comment: My question here is about a deletion vote on *my answer*, not the question.  I am not the person who asked that question.

Comment: @billynoah: `:%s/your/the/g`

Comment: the vim replacement is cute but no one voted to delete the question.  The deletion vote was cast on the answer.  Which is just weird to me, hence my question here on meta. Close votes happen on questions 50 times per second.  nothing to see here move along.  Deletion votes on legit answers inspire meta posts

Comment: @billynoah: Looks like Makoto has got it all mixed up, but I'll add that it's possible one of those who voted to close the question voted to delete your answer in hopes it'll be removed, thus accelerating the question's Roomba-deletion. If *that's* the case, I'd consider that an abuse of delete votes - because deleting an answer before the question with it is *not* the same as deleting the question directly, and answers should not be deleted *just because* somebody thinks the question is off-topic. Sadly, not even moderators can see who has cast delete votes before they've passed.